# Publish to wall facebook api works local but not live

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've tested on my local, and everything works fine. Pops out new window and posts. However, since pushing live. The live site facebook popup comes up but fades 2 seconds later, not to show itself again.

**Why would this happen?** What things do I need to be aware of between local and live sites that would cause a problem like this?

```
<script src='http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

  FB.init({appId: "11111818811881", status: true, cookie: true});

  function postToFeed(description) {

    // calling the API ...
    var obj = {
      method: 'feed',
      redirect_uri: 'https://thelivesite.com/dashboard/all/',
      link: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/',
      picture: 'https://www.thelivesite.com/static/images/logo.png',
      name: 'LiveSiteName',
      caption: 'Meow',
      description: description
    };

    function callback(response) {
      document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = "Post ID: " + response['post_id'];
    }

    FB.ui(obj, callback);
  }
</script>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">

<div id='fb-root'></div>                                           
<p style="cursor: pointer; display: inline-block; position: absolute; margin-left: -20px;">
     <a onclick='postToFeed("This is a message Cool beans."); return false;'></a>
</p>
<p id='msg'></p>
```

Thank you for your suggestions and advice in advance.

Comment: Have you changed the site url in App Settings?

Comment: I have not. Am I supposed to? All I have in my settings.py is the FACEBOOK_API_ID, FACEBOOK_API_KEY, and FACEBOOK_API_SECRET.

Answer (score 0):

- Go to > https://developers.facebook.com/apps
- Edit Your App
- Settings > Basic
- Website with Facebook Login
- In the Site URL, enter your site url as: http://www.yoursite.com/

Comment: No It didn't work. I actually don't have a Settings > Basic option :(

Comment: @Modelesq u didn't created a facebook app?? this article may help you : http://www.loginworks.com/technical-blogs/404-working-with-facebook-javascript-sdk

Comment: I created it. Made the changes and the popup still fails to show.